# Password requirements

Tags: c++

I'm trying to declare this string as `Invalid` but in an input like this:

`59G71341` or `8pjf7h14sx13` or `60s1v344`

My output is getting approved through my string if statement and is getting listed as `Valid`.

Could anyone guide me to why its passing through my if statement and labeling `Valid`!!

I haven't learned how to use a debugger yet so bare with me.

Task description:

> Declare a Boolean variable named goodPasswd. Use goodPasswd to output "Valid" if secretStr contains no more than 5 digits and secretStr's length is greater than or equal to 5, and "Invalid" otherwise.

> Ex: If the input is 80796, then the output is:
> Valid

> Ex: If the input is XBdg, then the output is:
> Invalid

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string secretStr;

    bool goodPasswd = false;
    cin >> secretStr;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < secretStr.length(); ++i)
    {
        if ((secretStr[i] >= 0) && (secretStr[i] <= 9))
        {
            ++counter;
        }
    }  //approves string if both true
    if ((counter <= 5) && (secretStr.length() >= 5))
    {
        goodPasswd = true;
    }
    else
    {
        goodPasswd = false;
    }

    if (goodPasswd)
    {
        cout << "Valid" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Print out the value of `(int)secretStr[0]` when `secretStr` is "123".  Is it the value you expect?  If not, look up "ASCII encoding" and "c++ character literal".

Comment: Side note, `bool goodPasswd = (counter <= 5) && (secretStr.length() >= 5);` is more concise/clearer than what you have there. Similarly you can do `cout << (goodPasswd ? "Valid" : "Invalid") << endl;`

Comment: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/13253010)

Comment: I was studying and seen that it is bad practice, but I do my work through Zybooks and I'm forced to use namespace for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ((secretStr[i] >= 0) && (secretStr[i] <= 9))
```

should be

```
if ((secretStr[i] >= '0') && (secretStr[i] <= '9'))
```

`0` and `9` are integers, but you are comparing characters, so you need to use the characters `'0'` and '`9`', or you could just use the `isdigit` function.

```
if (isdigit(secretStr[i]))
```

`isdigit` is declared in `#include <cctype>`

Not related to your question but you don't need to `goodPasswd` variable. Simply

```
if (counter <= 5 && secretStr.length() >= 5)
{
    cout << "Valid" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Invalid" << endl;
}
```

seems a bit cleaner to me.

Comment: Just tried and and it solved my issue! And the isdigit function was recommended but I didn't know how to implement it in a loop that scans through the index's! Thank you for giving an example on how to use it. I will be accepting your answer when it is available.

Comment: also I am doing this through ZyBooks and the questions don't allow me to edit some parts of the code. So I have to work with what they give me.